# Overwrite character in an array using C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

I'm creating a dynamic 2d character array in C:

Note: `rows` and `columns` are user input `integers`

```
char** items;
items = (char**)malloc(rows * sizeof(char*));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    items[i] = (char*)malloc(columns * sizeof(char));
}

int j;
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        items[i][j] = 'O';
    }
}
```

Later in my code, I attempt to overwrite a specific location in the array:

```
items[arbitraryRow][arbitraryColumn] = 'S';
```

But the result is that the characters in that row/column are now 'SO'

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:
This is how I'm printing the array:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    printf("[");
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        printf("'%s'", &items[i][j]);
        if(j != columns - 1)
            printf(", ");
    }
    printf("]");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: you can always use char *times = (char*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(char));
char c = times[j*rows + i];

Comment: How are you looking at them?  One byte of memory can't contain two characters.

Comment: Do you print your content like that: `printf("%s", items[arbitraryRow])`? And another question: Is the content of `items[arbitraryRow][arbitraryColumn]` really equal `'SO'` or `"SO"`? I mean usually characters constants (quoted with `'`) only contain one single character.

Comment: You can skip `sizeof(char)` since that is by definition 1

Comment: What you are allocating is not a 2D array but an array of pointers. Don't cast returns from `malloc`. What do you mean by your characters are now 'SO', this ain't a `char`.

Comment: You should use `%c` to print a character. Using `%s` and passing the pointer will look for a NULL terminated string, which can be `SO` or can contain some junk characters afrer `SO` (as there is no guarantee that byte with value 0 exists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not storing strings you're storing characters so all you can read is one character so that'd be the S

My suspision is that the next character is an O so when you look at it as a string you get SO

```
printf("'%c'", items[i][j]);
```

Comment: How can I print the characters as characters instead of strings?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing characters and reading strings. Try reading character back from the Array.

Change your code to:

```
int i; 
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
{
     printf("[");
     int j;
     for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
     {
         printf("'%c'", items[i][j]);
         if(j != columns - 1)
             printf(", ");
     }
     printf("]");
     printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, `%c` was the trick, although I had to use `items[i][j]` instead of `&items[i][j]`